# Hide/Show material components

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a simple `mat-card` that I want to show/hide based on a value. However, `*ngIf` directive does't seem to work on it.

```
<mat-card *ngIf="displayNoSignUp">Simple card</mat-card>
```

Is there a way to do it using a directive on the material components? Or should it be wrapped inside an `html div`?

Comment: Many ways to do it. If you say *ngIf is not working, you could try [class.hidden]="displayNoSignup" and the set display:node in the hidden css class. This would hide it but the markup would still be there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your syntax is correct, and it should work. Check again the value of `displayNoSignUp` in your component.

Comment: Excuse thy lack of attention. The boolean values were reversed.